# How to time runtime on linux

Tags: linux, runtime, executable

Is there a simple way to time runtime? I am running an executable on linux and want to know how long it takes to run without having to time manually

Comment: To time program foo, type `time foo`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use `time <your exectuable>`

```
time ./executable
```

For the more available options you can see the manual using `man time`.